# Getting an error while implementing memoization in the java code

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, memoization

Memoization is giving me wrong answers. Please can some one help me out here. Without memorization, I am getting the right answers as in function `targetBestR`, but in the memoized function `targetBestM`, I am getting the wrong values being stored in the array list for the respective keys.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class TargetSumBest {

public static ArrayList<Integer> targetBestR(int n, int arr[]){
    if(n==0) return new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if(n<0) return null;
    ArrayList<Integer> shortestCombo=null;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        //System.out.println(i);
        //System.out.println(arr[i]);
        int rem=n-arr[i];
        //System.out.println(n+"-"+i+"="+rem);
        ArrayList<Integer> tar=targetBestR(rem, arr);
        if(tar!=null) {
            tar.add(arr[i]);
            if(shortestCombo==null||tar.size()<shortestCombo.size()) {
                shortestCombo=tar;
            }
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(n+"value"+shortestCombo);
    return shortestCombo;
}   
public static ArrayList<Integer> targetBestM(int n, int arr[], HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> memo){
    if(n==0) return new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if(n<0) return null;
    if(memo.containsKey(n)) return memo.get(n);
    ArrayList<Integer> shortestCombo=null;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        //System.out.println(i);
        //System.out.println(arr[i]);
        int rem=n-arr[i];
        //System.out.println(n+"-"+i+"="+rem);
        ArrayList<Integer> tar=targetBestM(rem, arr,memo);
        if(tar!=null) {
            tar.add(arr[i]);
            if(shortestCombo==null||tar.size()<shortestCombo.size()) {
                shortestCombo=tar;
                
            }
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(n+"value"+shortestCombo);
    memo.put(n, shortestCombo);
    return shortestCombo;
}   
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n=8; int arr[]= {1,4,2};
    
    System.out.println(targetBestM(n, arr, new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>()));
    System.out.println(targetBestR(n, arr));
}
}//error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to find the problem.  The array passed into the HashMap keeps getting used and added to.  Was able to fix it by creating new ArrayLists when reading and writing from the HashMap.

when reading...

```
    if (memo.containsKey(n)) {
        System.out.println(indent + n +  " memo.get(n) = " + memo.get(n));
        return new ArrayList<>(memo.get(n));
    }
```

when writing...

```
    memo.put(n, new ArrayList<>(shortestCombo));
```

Comment: Hi Jose, I tried to do it this way but still it is not working, the output of memoization method I am getting is, [4,1,1,1,1]

Comment: I updated the answer.  There are two changes.